# Can you attach a connector meant for a rigid PCB to a flex PCB?

Tags: pcb, connector, pcb-assembly

Is it possible to connect a standard mezzanine connector to a flex PCB?

I.e. could I use a mezzanine connector meant for connecting two rigid PCBs in a situation where one is flex and one is rigid?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

What is usually done is that a stiffener is added to the area of the connector.  The stiffener is usually FR4 (with no copper) glued/epoxied to the flex on the backside of the connector.

Answer (score 2):

In general all SMT components are designed to be attached to a rigid PCB; you can attach them to flexible PCBs provided that the flex is limited at the points where the component is attached.  As Aaron pointed out, this can be achieved with stiffeners but it may be that the application results in minimal bending without stiffeners.  What counts as acceptable is rather dependent on the particular parts, the application and the required reliability/lifetime, so it’s not easy to quantify.